# Extract backup messages and/or installed apps list from iCloud programmatically

Tags: javascript, python, ios, scripting, icloud

I'm creating an iOS app and I want to show the user their installed apps. When user clicks on an app in the list, if it's a messaging/social media app, then I want to show the latest messages.
So far I've found how to get other data from iCloud but not the data I'm looking for.
I've found this [pyicloud](https://pypi.org/project/pyicloud/) Python module, and this [JS project](https://github.com/MauriceConrad/iCloud-API).

I'm wondering if there's an open-source project, or library on this matter.
Any thoughts on the matter would be much appreciated.

I'm open to ideas and solutions in any language it's available in, but would prefer Python or Javascript.

Comment: Did you find any clues? I am trying to do get calls, messages and app list but got stuck.